# " Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot' " in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

While trying to run any flutter project on Android Studio, I am getting this particular error :

```
[+11147 ms] [+13655 ms] ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.2/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
[        ] [   +1 ms]       io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
[        ] [        ]                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looked on the net for quite a while but couldn't find any viable solution. Can anyone help with a fix?

Comment: Its work for me: 
$ flutter pub cache repair

Comment: For Flutter iOS - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71207042/1318946

Comment: This is a platform related issue and has to do with a dependency used. I advise you run `flutter pub upgrade` to upgrade

Answer (score 105):

I faced the same issue. I fixed it.

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
flutter pub upgrade
```

Comment: Not helpful. I am already on `stable`.

Comment: @MichałDobiDobrzański did you find a fix?

Comment: I was able to fix this by running `flutter doctor` and reading the output. For me, the Visual Studio requirement is now 2019 or above, and I had 2017, after installing VS 2022 and for good measure running `flutter upgrade`  `flutter pub upgrade` and `flutter pub outdated` I am now up and running again

Comment: @JoseMelendez I think that `flutter pub upgrade` helped me with that - dependencies were out of date. This happened after upgrading to Flutter `2.10` from `2.8`.

Comment: Using `flutter pub upgrade` also helped me.

Comment: using ```flutter pub upgrade --major-versions``` also helped to automatically update & resolve outdated dependencies.

Comment: Add this under dependencies => 
dependencies: 
  platform: ^3.1.0

Comment: The only thing that could help me was to delete the pubspec.lock file from the project folder and only then run flutter clean and then

flutter pub get

Comment: try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831554/13059465